# Sqldf join using row id in r

Tags: r, sqldf

For the data structure in the table below (peak_refined) I'd like to match the column ID with the unique row.names of the second table ('dat'). I'd prefer to use the sqldf package but stuck with referencing the row.name. Tested code given below for any pointers. Ideally I expect to retrieve the 'Time' from records 1 and 6 of table 'dat'.

**Table peak_refined**

```
structure(list(IDs = c(1L, 6L, 28L, 31L, 668L, 2841L, 2862L, 
2865L, 2906L, 2917L, 2925L, 2957L, 2960L, 2966L, 2984L, 2993L, 
3000L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("X1", "X2", "X3", 
"X4", "X5", "X6", "X7", "X8", "X9", "X10", "X11", "X12", "X13", 
"X14", "X15", "X16", "X17"))
```

**Table Dat:**

```
structure(list(Time=c("2021-06-18 12:36:00", "2021-06-18 12:38:00", "2021-06-18 12:40:00",
```

"2021-06-18 12:42:00", "2021-06-18 12:44:00", "2021-06-18 12:46:00",
"2021-06-18 12:48:00", "2021-06-18 12:50:00", "2021-06-18 12:52:00",
"2021-06-18 12:54:00")))

```
 [1] "2021-06-18 12:36:00" "2021-06-18 12:38:00" "2021-06-18 12:40:00"
 [4] "2021-06-18 12:42:00" "2021-06-18 12:44:00" "2021-06-18 12:46:00"
 [7] "2021-06-18 12:48:00" "2021-06-18 12:50:00" "2021-06-18 12:52:00"
[10] "2021-06-18 12:54:00"
```

**Tested Code:**

```
library(sqldf)
sq <- sqldf("SELECT peak_refined.IDs, dat.row.names
FROM peak_refined
INNER JOIN dat
ON peak_refined.IDs = dat.row.names")
```

Comment: sqldf works with data frames.  The second object is not a data frame.  Example 4f in the Examples section of ?sqldf shows an example working with row names.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck - Thank you, the example was very helpful. Didn't know it existed.